# What is a reliable way to know if libcurl finished downloading a file?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have written this basic class:

```
class SteamHTTP
{
public:
    SteamHTTP();
    virtual  ~SteamHTTP();

    void DownloadAllGames(const wxString& username, wxGauge* progress);

private:
    CURL* m_curl;
    std::stringstream m_currentRequestString;

private:
    static size_t write_func(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
    static int progress_func(void *clientp, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow);
};


SteamHTTP::SteamHTTP()
{
    m_curl = curl_easy_init();
}

SteamHTTP::~SteamHTTP()
{
    curl_easy_cleanup(m_curl);
}

size_t SteamHTTP::write_func(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    SteamHTTP* ptr = reinterpret_cast<SteamHTTP*>(userdata);
    ptr->m_currentRequestString << data;
    return size*nmemb;
}

int SteamHTTP::progress_func(void *clientp, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow)
{
    wxGauge* ptr = reinterpret_cast<wxGauge*>(clientp);
    ptr->SetValue(dlnow * 100.0f / dlnow );
    return 0;
}

void SteamHTTP::DownloadAllGames(const wxString& username, wxGauge* gauge)
{
    std::string url;
    CURLcode result;

    // Build URL
    url = std::string("http://steamcommunity.com/id/") + username.mbc_str() + std::string("/games?tab=all&xml=1");

    // Set URL
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    // Follow redirection
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    // Data Callback
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, SteamHTTP::write_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);

    // Progress Callback
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, SteamHTTP::progress_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, gauge);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);

    // Perform
    result = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
    if (result != 0){
        wxMessageBox(curl_easy_strerror(result), wxMessageBoxCaptionStr, wxICON_ERROR|wxOK);
    }
}
```

What I struggle with is to tell reliably when libcurl is actually finished. Is there a callback for that? I would need that to parse the data downloaded.

**What is the best way to tell if libcurl is done and I can process the data?**

*p.s.: This code is work in progress, checks need yet to be written etc.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When curl_easy_perform() returns, it is done. It is as simple as that. Check the return code to figure out if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

in [CURLOPTPROGRESSFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSFUNCTION) callback there are few parameters:

```
int function(void *clientp, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow);
```

`dltotal` is the total bytes to be downloaded, and dlnow is the number of bytes downloaded so far. The download is completed when `dltotal == dlnow`.

> `dltotal` is the total number of bytes libcurl expects to download in this transfer. `dlnow` is the number of bytes downloaded so far

Comment: Found out, this does not work. Because if you have an ASCII Transfer, the sizes are always 0. Which sucks.